# How to fix screen tear when a monitor runs on integrated Intel graphics and another on Nvidia GPU

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, 20.04, intel-graphics, tearing

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 (dual booted alongside Windows 10) on my Lenovo IdeaPad L340-15IRH laptop, which has a GTX 1050 GPU.
I'm using a dual monitor setup composed of the laptop's integrated monitor, connected to Intel graphics, and an external HDMI monitor (well, a TV actually), connected to the Nvidia GPU.

Here's the prolem: while the integrated monitor looks fine, I get scren tear on the external monitor. I tried switching to the proproetary nvidia drivers instead of the nouveau drivers to fix this from the nvidia settings program, which works for the external monitor, except merely switching to the proprietary drivers causes the integrated monitor to now get massive screen tear, even though it worked fine before.

I can't fix the integrated monitor tear from the nvidia settings since it is connected to intel graphics, so I looked online and found several guides on fixing screen tear on intel graphics, all of them suggested creating the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` and writing to it some variant of the following code:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier "Intel Graphics"
   Driver "intel"
   Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"
   Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

Except doing so causes the integrated monitor to stay on a black screen after reboot. I can get the monitor to work again by deleting the 20-intel.conf file.

I tried switching back to the nouveau drivers and try to fix the tearing from there. After looking through some forums I decided to create the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and add this to it:

```
Section "Device"
 Identifier "My Graphics"
 Driver "nouveau"
 Option "GLXVBlank" "on"
EndSection
```

And while this does fix the tearing on the external monitor, it causes the integrated monitor to remain blank.

So it seems as though I can get one monitor to work properly but not the other. I don't really mind which driver I need to use in order ro solve this (although I've read here and there that proprietary drivers have better performance in games), I just want it to work. I'm new to Linux and any help is appreceated.

Comment: I'd turn off the nvidia card in bios if possible. My thinkpads are running on intel, with two external monitors without problems. Best results I got with Xubuntu  and compton (or pico) as compositor (not using the Xcompmgr which tears)

Comment: How does that work given that the HDMI output of my laptop is connected to the nvidia card?

Comment: I've never heard of that. The [Spec](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/IdeaPad/ideapad_L340_15IRH_Gaming/ideapad_L340_15IRH_Gaming_Spec.PDF) shows that you can have either Intel or nivdia with external monitor.

Comment: Ok, this will probably help. However, I feel reluctant to turn off the graphics card in the bios, since I would still like to use it for games, especially on windows. Any way around that?

Comment: Use ONE graphics card. Either INTEL (which saves power) or NVIDIA. I believe the X-Server can't cope with both correctly

Comment: Well, that's a shame. In that case, I think I'll leave things as they are. I can live with the tearing, but not without the gpu, since I use that for gaming on windows. Thanks for the help

Comment: Ok, still not sure, therefore as comment: Have you looked into bumblebee? It is supposed to support both graphic modes. You basic problem seems to be that the refresh rate is different on the two monitors. What does `xrandr`say? We might get a clue there.